# How to identify syncopation?

Tags: theory, syncopation

For the reference, I'm just started learning music theory for less than half a year and just barely touched on the syncopation topic. It seems that syncopation is not easy for me to identify at all.

I assume that on a normal 4/4 pop song, if the synth is played in between the beats then it's syncopated. But in practice, for example: The chorus on **" Closer"** by Chainsmokers

(which I've been informed to be a syncopated section) my mind can't quite pay attention to both the synth and beat counting at the same time.

Another case: Intro section of **"Need You Now"** by Hot Chip (synths appear at 0:29)

I feel that the synth is placed "weirdly" and could be syncopated but I'm really not sure.

Is there any effective and easier way to identify this?

Comment: `my mind can't quite pay attention to both the synth and beat counting at the same time` try tapping your foot on the beat, you shouldn't have to think too much about this. You can then cross-reference the synth and your feet - if it's with your foot it's on the beat, etc.. This has helped me out more than I'd like to admit!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Piano and Theory Terms- Syncopation?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/63656/piano-and-theory-terms-syncopation)

Answer (score 2):

First - don't worry about it.  Syncopation is a constant feature of popular (and other) music.  You'd almost be surprised if everyone DID follow a plain 'four on the floor' rhythm!   What's so important about labelling a rhythm 'syncopated' or not?

But if you want to, tap your foot to the music.  Where a prominent rhythm in the music aligns with your foot taps, it's not syncopated.  Where it doesn't, it is.

Comment: And the reason it's so popular is because a very useful expression tool. It's very important part of a lot of music. Give a listen to "Tequila" by the Champs or "Take Five" by Dave Brubeck. It's rhythm on top of rhythm.

Comment: 'Take Five' is interesting.  The accompaniment rhythm is slightly syncopated, but in a very regular pattern.  The melody isn't syncopated at all until the middle 8.   It's like being in 5/4 is sufficient rhythmic novelty - let it sink in for a bit before 'working against it'.

Answer (score 0):

For me, your two songs don't seem that great as examples of syncopation.  The first one was a bit syncopated in the background chords of the chorus but there must be lots of better examples than that.  I am from a classical background.  I suggest you listen to the opening of Mozart's Symphony no. 25.  You will be able to recognize and feel the syncopation in the violins.

Comment: If you can feel the basic 4 beats in the bar, you can then feel the 'off beats' against the basic beats.